# Insert a list inside a cell of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

When I try to insert a list in a DataFrame cell, I have the following error:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

My code:

```
di = [3.14, 9.81, 9.55, 9.84]
for i in df_mast.index:
    arr = [[]]
    x = df_mast['avg_speed_bin'][i] 
    for j in di:
        arr.append(x/(1.5 + (0.8 * j /(7/x)**0.5)))
    df_mast['TI_wake'][i] = arr
```

df_mast['avg_speed_bin'] would be dataframe with single values in each cell.

but when I define **arr** as below, it works

```
arr = [[]]
```

But then the result is:

```
[[],
 1.2712604797925258,
 0.5739782581177619,
 0.5865184221642806,
 0.5725657374108474]
```

How can I remove the brackets inside the result? If I define **arr** as a single bracket ([]) it does not work, but if I define it as double brackets ([[]]) it works, but then I have a single bracket in my result.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You are appending to the outer list in arr, you need to access the inner list which can be done by doing `arr[0].append(x/(1.5 + (0.8 * j /(7/x)**0.5)))`

Alternatively, you could,

```
di = [3.14, 9.81, 9.55, 9.84]
for i in df_mast.index:
    arr = []
    x = df_mast['avg_speed_bin'][i] 
    for j in di:
        arr.append(x/(1.5 + (0.8 * j /(7/x)**0.5)))
    df_mast['TI_wake'][i] = [arr]
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. I fixed this issue now by df_mast['TI_wake'] = df_mast['TI_wake'].astype('object')

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem if you just do the following:

```
df_mast['TI_wake'] = df_mast['TI_wake'].astype('object')
```